# Unable to fetch lookup field values using REST api

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column

I am using REST api to fetch data from a SharePoint list.

I am able to get data using this query:

```
requestUri = "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Data')/items?$select=ID,Title,Department/Title&$expand=Department
```

However when I use this query:

```
requestUri = "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Data')/items(6)"
```

Or this query:

```
requestUri = "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Data')/items?$select=ID,Title,Department/Title&$expand=Department&$filter=ID eq 6"
```

I am not getting the data from the lookup fields.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting any error while calling this endpoint ?

Comment: There are no errors. I am getting the concerned record, but the lookup fields are showing some `_deferred` entry

Comment: You should get the lookup data in `data.d.results[0].Department.Title`. Also check if there is any department selected for item with ID=6.

Comment: Holy!! I chose some random ID, and all the 10 lookup fields were empty for that particular record. Changed the ID, and it is working..

Comment: Great. Glad it helped you. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your endpoint like:

```
requestUri = "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Data')/items(6)?$select=ID,Title,Department/Title&$expand=Department
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue.